# Is sending logs from a device the same as beats in logstash?

Tags: logging, logstash

I’m curious if I tell my router to send it’s logs to my Logstash instance, is that the same thing as Beats?

I’ve seen several articles walking you through setting up Filebeats on your device.

What are the benefits to Filebeats versus just telling your device to send to the Logstash server?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Router are usually able to send logs via syslog.

You need some process to accept these log-events.
This can be rsyslog, Logstash or Filebeat.

Logstash and Filebeat are tools that collect log-events from files and/or receive log-events via network and forward these log-events to some destination.
Filebeat is more modern and consumes fewer resources that Logstash.
Logstash is super versatile.

Filebeat syslog-input: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-input-syslog.html

Please be aware that there's more than one syslog-format.